# Shell script reading/formatting config file

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I've searched a few places and didn't find one for my needs, basically here's the config:

```
name1 = value1;
name2= value2
name3 =value3 // comments

name4=value4 //empty line above and/or below
```

I need a shell script that reads the config file and parse all the name / value pairs with starting/trailing semicolons/spaces removed and comments as well as empty lines ignored.

I first tried

```
while read -r name value
do
echo "Content of $name is ${value//\"/}"
done < $1
```

I tried to trim `name` and `value` by:

```
"${var//+([[:space:]])/}"
```

but still not sure how to remove the semicolon and ignore the empty lines and comments?

Comment: You are asking us wriite a complete parser for an incompletely specified file format?  In shell script?  Seriously?

Comment: A somewhat more sane approach would be to preprocess the input to remove comments and value-final semicolon terminators, and normalize whitespace.  Then the rest is extremely easy.

Comment: @tripleee Yes I see, the format is just what's in the first quoted part, name value pairs separated by equal sign, with optional spaces and comments.

Comment: If you are fine with a Bash solution, replace `< $1` (which should properly be `< "$1")` with something like `< <(sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's%[[:space:]]*//.*%%' -e 's/;$//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*/ /' "$1")`

Comment: Or why worry about a `"parser"`, just change the comment identifiers to `#`, remove the spaces on either side of the `=` sign, and then `source config.file` into your script... That would make a lot more sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where IFS could be used. You'll have to rely on sed, however, and assume a well-formed config file. No multiline values like that.

```
parseconf() {
  sed -e 's/^[ ;]*//' \
      -e 's/[ ;]*$//' \
      -e 's/\/\/.*//' \
      -e 's/ *= */=/' $1 \
  | while IFS="=" read -r name value
  do
    [ -n "$name" ] && echo "name=$name value=$value"
  done
}
parseconf $1
```